# Inserting HTML into XML view with captcha

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently working on a page that is made with openui5, what I need to do is to insert a captcha, but as far as I know there is no captcha in openui5, what I was trying is to insert HTML content into this.

The problem is, my views are in XML and I did try to insert directly using  tags and changing the content, but wasn't possible, it says incorrect xml parsing.

Part of my code of where I want to input my html div:

```
<Page id="page1" class="marginBoxContent" showHeader="false" showFooter="false" enableScrolling="true">
<content>
  <Image src="../../image/logo.svg" />
  <l:Grid
    defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
    width="100%">
    <l:content>
      <f:Form id="FormChange354"
        minWidth="1024"
        maxContainerCols="2"
        editable="true">
        <f:layout>
          <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="3"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="4"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1" />
        </f:layout>
        <f:formContainers>
          <f:FormContainer>
            <f:formElements>
              <f:FormElement label="{i18n>Language}">
                <f:fields>
                  <Select id="animationSelect" selectedKey="en" change="languageChange">
                      <core:Item text="English" key="en" />
                    <core:Item text="Português" key="pt" />
                      <core:Item text="Español" key="es" />
                      <layoutData>
                        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                      </layoutData>
                    </Select>
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
            <f:formElements>
              <f:FormElement label="{i18n>User}">
                <f:fields>
                  <Input id="username" value="" type="Email" />
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
            <f:formElements>
              <f:FormElement label="{i18n>Password}">
                <f:fields>
                  <Input id="password" type="Password" placeholder="" value="" />
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
            <f:formElements>
              <f:FormElement label="">
                <f:fields>
                  <Button id="btnLogin" text="{i18n>Sigin}" type="Emphasized" press="login" />
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
          </f:FormContainer>
        </f:formContainers>
      </f:Form>
      <l:VerticalLayout>
          <Link text="{i18n>CreateUser}" press="navCreateUser" />
          <Link text="{i18n>RecoverPass}" press="navRecoverPass" />
          <Link text="{i18n>ChangePass}" press="navChangePass" />
      </l:VerticalLayout>
    </l:content>
  </l:Grid>
</content>
```

I want to insert exaclty here:

```
<f:formElements>
          <f:FormElement label="">
            <f:fields>
              <Button id="btnLogin" text="{i18n>Sigin}" type="Emphasized" press="login" />
            </f:fields>
          </f:FormElement>
        </f:formElements>
```

Inside the fields xml or before, because the captcha will appear above the login button.

The content of the div I want to insert is from google captcha:

```
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="your_site_key"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible"></div>
```

Couldn't have success yet, anybody can help me with that?
Maybe is something about the namespace, I don't know, here is my namespace config:

```
  <mvc:View
  height="100%"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  controllerName="hiddenName.app.login.view.Login">
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: read the documentation https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/be54950cae1041f59d4aa97a6bade2d8

Comment: Probably you should implement your own custom control and there you would implement a renderer which can generate any HTML you want. Refer to https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thank you for every help. I got some help from all comments, what I did was declare the namespace to html:

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  height="100%"
  controllerName="hiddenName.app.login.view.Login"
>
```

And simply added the tag as I show down here:

```
<html:div id="recaptchaGoogle" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="yourKey"></html:div>
```

Also remember to declare the import of the google js(added it on my index):

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to get this captcha answer and pass or not to the login.

With that, the captcha appears and is generated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, do it work also from launchpad ? did you find a way to get the captcha answer ?

Answer (score 1):

To insert HTML in a XML view you could use the HTML control from the sap.ui.core library. You will have to escape the HTML text before using it in XML.

```
<core:HTML content='&lt;div id=&quot;recaptcha&quot; class=&quot;g-recaptcha&quot; data-sitekey=&quot;your_site_key&quot; data-callback=&quot;onSubmit&quot; data-size=&quot;invisible&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' />
```